# Is it recommended or good practice to use a directive that matches standard html tags?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wanted to write a directive that only applied to `IMG` tags throughout my whole page, and initially I thought I would have to decorate each tag with a custom directive name, such as:

`<img my-img />`.

But, while I was putting together some sample code for this question, I decided to see if the directive would match on the element `IMG` itself. And it worked!

Here's what I did: http://plnkr.co/edit/z4n4a3MN89nRNYyXKCih?p=preview

```
app.directive('img', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.bind('load', function () {
                element.addClass('fadeIn');
            });
            element.bind('error', function () {
                element.removeClass('fadeIn');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

As you can see, I wanted all images on a page to fade in when they loaded. I wanted to do this in an angular fashion without using jQuery, so I thought this was a good approach, but is it good practice? In my case, I really do want this logic to apply to all the images on my page (and there may be hundreds), so I thought this would be a clean way of doing it, but for the life of me I haven't found anywhere where anyone else does this (i.e., matching a directive to an `IMG` tag or any standard tag for that matter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would avoid the img directive.  Take note that Angular has already added their own directives which match html element names (e.g. - form, input, select, script), so it seems conceivable that there could potentially be a conflict if they (or any library you use) utilize the same directive name.  And do you really want to fade in all images?  What if you use an image as a decoration on the page?

It seems like it would be best to instead add the attribute.  It's very intuitive with nominal effort.  If you don't care about the built in  attributes, you could also create your own element (e.g. ).

Comment: I am of the same thought wanting to avoid using the img directive, but I am in a unique situation where what we used is tightly controlled. It is a strictly internal application and only runs on one machine on a Chrome browser.

Comment: I really do want to fade all images. This app is very image heavy, showing scollable lists of hundreds of images, changing background images for different areas of the app, etc. I've tested the solution I arrived at in the plunker sample and it makes the app seem very fluid and smooth, so I may stick with it until I come up with something better.